# Adding HDFStore to executable with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, hdf5

I created an `executable` with `PyInstaller` on `MacOs`. The python program includes a `HDFStore` file to save dataframes. Running the code in PyCharm works fine, but when I create the `executable` I get the following error message:

```
File "H5F.c", line 620, in H5Fopen
    unable to open file
File "H5VLcallback.c", line 3502, in H5VL_file_open
    failed to iterate over available VOL connector plugins
File "H5PLpath.c", line 579, in H5PL__path_table_iterate
    can't iterate over plugins in plugin path '(null)'
File "H5PLpath.c", line 620, in H5PL__path_table_iterate_process_path
    can't open directory: /usr/local/hdf5/lib/plugin
File "H5VLcallback.c", line 3351, in H5VL__file_open
    open failed
File "H5VLnative_file.c", line 97, in H5VL__native_file_open
    unable to open file
File "H5Fint.c", line 1990, in H5F_open
    unable to read superblock
File "H5Fsuper.c", line 617, in H5F__super_read
    truncated file: eof = 96, sblock->base_addr = 0, stored_eof = 2048

End of HDF5 error back trace

Unable to open/create file 'store.h5'
```

I created the `executable` using

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data "store.h5:." main.py
```

Why can't the program open the file? Is it not included the right way into the `executable`?

Comment: HDFS is probably not installed on your system https://forum.hdfgroup.org/t/cant-open-directory-usr-local-hdf5-lib-plugin/9738